# access is denied IIS server problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have no problem compiling and viewing my asp.net application using visual studio 2008

but when i try to see it the IIS server (asp.net 4.0...)

i get this message:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Access is denied.

Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. The server may not be configured for access to the requested URL. 

Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's administrator for additional assistance.

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

i did already run this update:

```
asp_net_regiis.exe
```

is there something else that i should configure?

i've tried to switch the framework to `2.0` and that failed as well however i got a different message for 2.0:

```
Server Application Unavailable

The web application you are attempting to access on this web server is currently unavailable.  Please hit the "Refresh" button in your web browser to retry your request.

Administrator Note: An error message detailing the cause of this specific request failure can be found in the application event log of the web server. Please review this log entry to discover what caused this error to occur.
```

any guidance would be most appreciated.

Comment: The error indicates that either you or the application pool identity account don't have permissions to view the requested file.

Comment: Did you read that last line? The one about the eventlog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have authentication issues. Make sure that you enable anonymous access to your virtual directory and if you are using windows authentication on your site, that you also check off the option for "integrated windows authentication"

Comment: where can i find that check box?>

Comment: In IIS 5, under Directory Security --> Anonymous Access and Authentication Control. In IIS 7 got to features view --> authentication

Comment: another question for you: i am inserting data into a database, and it is giving me this error on the IIS server, however it works with the compiler: Server Error in '/' Application.

Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details:

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

Comment: That's probably because you haven't granted access to your Windows domain account to your SQL Server Box. You need to go to SSMS --> Security --> Logins --> New Login and do a Search for your Windows Account and add it as a valid login. You then need to select your database, expand it and a new user selecting the login you created in the previous step. But if it doesn't matter to you whether you use Integrated windows auth to connect to your SQL Server or not, I would advise you to use SQL Server Auth to connect to your SQL database and change the connection string appropriately.

Comment: http://connectionstrings.com/ has some examples for different servers and authentication mechanisms. Check it out.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Windows Authentication?  Verify that your user account has access to the folder the web site is in.

Are you using Anonymous Authentication?  Verify that it's enabled in IIS.

Comment: im using win auth, yes it has full access

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the NETWORK SERVICE account (or whatever system account you're using) has permissions to that folder.

Comment: the system account has full control

Comment: On the Home Directory tab, what are the Read/Write and Execute permissions? Make sure that at least Read and Scripts Only are selected.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and this was how I resolved it:

1. Add IIS_IUSRS to the permission in IIS: Right click your project >> edit permission >> security >> Add >> Type IIS_IUSRS >> OK
2. In your IIS features view >> Authentication >> Enable Windows Authentication and if you want, Basic Authentication.
3. Relaunch your App, and you should be OK

Answer (score 1):

The error seems clear, you don't have the privileges needed.

Try running VS as Admin.

If you're in a company network and you can't 'elevate' enough, there is the new IIS Express to address just that problem.

Comment: thank yo uvery much for yoru response. ive confirmed that on that folder the specified account has full control

Comment: It's not just the folder. IIS has settings too.

Comment: where can i find this please?

Answer (score 1):

Permissions could definitely be a problem.

But are you sure you deployed your ASP.Net application correctly?

The easiest, surest way is to use the "Publish Web" tool from Visual Studio:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983453.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can try change folder permissions:

```
right click on the folder -> 
properties -> 
security tab -> 
edit -> 
add permissions to IIS user
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a bunch of solutions but the final stroke was enabling Windows Authentication. My website was set to log in the user automatically based on their windows account.

You need to first install that capability and then enable it for your site in IIS: https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication